# Variáveis invertendo(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sei que dá pra fazer de outras maneiras, mas fiz limitado aos ifs. Desejo saber o porquê de estar invertendo os resultados na última parte do código.

```
from random import randint
    
pedra, papel, tesoura = "1", "2", "3"
    
print("[1] Pedra\n[2] Papel\n[3] Tesoura")
p = int(input("Pense no que vai jogar: \n"))
d, e, c = "Você perdeu!", "Empate!", "Você ganhou!"
pe, pa, te = "Pedra", "Papel", "Tesoura"
    
if p == 1:
    print("Você jogou:", pa)
elif p == 2:
    print("Você jogou:", pe)
elif p == 3:
    print("Você jogou:", te)
    
pc = randint(1, 3)  
    
if pc == 1:
    print("PC jogou:", pa)
elif pc == 2:
    print("PC jogou:", pe)
elif pc == 3:
    print("PC jogou:", te)
    
if pc == p:
    print(e)
elif pc == 1 and p == 2:
    print(d)
elif pc == 2 and p == 1:
    print(c)
elif pc == 3 and p == 1:
    print(d)
elif pc == 1 and p == 3:
    print(c)
elif pc == 3 and p == 2:
    print(c)
elif pc == 2 and p == 3:
    print(d)
```

Comment: Falamos Pedra, Papel e Tesoura... Vc colocou 1 = papel, 2 = pedra, 3 = Tesoura. Aí vc deixou seu código confuso. Muda os valores para 1 = pedra, 2 = papel, 3 = tesoura e refaz os `if`. Vai facilitar para vc. O erro está nos outros ifs e não nos dois últimos.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif pc == 1 and p == 2:
    print(c)
elif pc == 2 and p == 1:
    print(d)
elif pc == 3 and p == 1:
    print(c)
elif pc == 1 and p == 3:
    print(d)
elif pc == 3 and p == 2:
    print(d)
elif pc == 2 and p == 3:
    print(c)
```

O problema era que onde o jogador ganhava, era printado a variárel que o mostrava como perdedor. Basta susbtituir, no último if, onde tem "c" por "d" e vice-versa, conforme mostrado no código acima.